# Setting array as hash's value in Redis

Tags: ruby, hash, redis

I'm using redis with ruby and I'd like redis to make a hash in which the value is an array. However, the array is a value to a key, which is a value for another key (shortly - a hash in another hash).

```
arr = ["this", "is", "an", "array"]
r = Redis.new
r.hset("super_key", "key", arr)
```

which gives me error: `ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command`.

I'd expect the hash look something like this:

```
{ "super_key" => { "key" => ["this", "is", "an", "array"] } }
```

So what would be the correct way of performing this action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is what's making that method angry, but it does look like you're using it in a way it doesn't allow.  From [the Redis gem documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/redis/):

> Redis only stores strings as values. If you want to store an object, you can use a serialization mechanism such as JSON...

So try storing `array.to_json`, and use `JSON.parse(obj)` to get it back again.